# is possible to open Phone app from Widget in iOS 17?

Tags: widget, ios17

is possible to open Phone app from Widget in iOS 17??

From iOS 17 beta, iOS Contact app have an interactive widget with call and message button, that has action to open Phone, Messenger, Whatsapp, etc.

It's any API available to open another app from iOS widget?